# binding Enter key to jquery ui dialog button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two buttons on my jquery dialogue Ok and cancel. I want that when user press Enter on currently opened Jquery ui dialogue, then it behaves like Ok is clicked. buttons are defined like this:

```
     $("#dialog-confirm").dialog({
                    autoOpen: true,
                    resizable: true,
                    modal: true,
                    width: 458,
                    Height: 184,

                    buttons: {
                        "Login": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");  
 $("#frmsetAccount").submit();                        
                        },
                        "Cancel": function () {
                            $(this).dialog("close");                           

                        }
                    }
                });
    });
```

Please suggest solution to it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use KeyPress or KeyUp events

```
$('#targetElement').on('keypress', function(e) {
 var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
 if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
   //close your dialog box. -make sure you get the dialog object first. then close it. or call some function which is in ok button. 
 }
});
```

keyup

```
$('#targetElement').keyup(function(e) {
     var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
     if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
       //Do something
     }
    });
```

Comment: Do I need to write same code in if condition which I wrote in Ok function ?

Comment: how to get dialog object ? using $(this) ? and what will be its use

Comment: +1 just missing this line 'return false;'  after any logic you want it to run. If not what will happen is run mayb 2 or 3 times the same function.

Other than that this works perfectly fine.

PS: I recommend using " $.ui.keyCode.ENTER " instead of the number 13 in the IF statement... but thats just my preference i dislike magic numbers.

Answer (score 2):

I realize this post is old, but these responses don't really answer the question. Adding a hotkey event to a jQuery dialog is simple, if you set your dialog up correctly. I wrote some code below that is generic for most use cases.

You can view a working copy at 
[https://jsfiddle.net/bsalines/xpvt214o/3180/](https://jsfiddle.net/bsalines/xpvt214o/3180/#&togetherjs=Jw5QB9O0Ga)

```
$('<div id="yourJqueryDialogId"></div>').appendTo('body')
    .html(html) //add your custom html to be displayed in dialog
    .dialog({
        modal: true,
        title: 'Some Title',
        autoOpen: true,
        width: 500,
        height: 450,
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,

        buttons: {
            Cancel: {
                text: "Cancel",
                class: "model-cancel",
                click: function() {
                    // Add your code if you want to do something on close/cancel/exit
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();
                }
            },
            Save: {
                text: "Update",
                class: "model-update",
                id: "yourJqueryButtonId", // id for hotkey
                click: function() {
                    //Add your code here for hotkey and update/save/submit
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    $(this).dialog('destroy').remove();

                },

            },
        }
    });

$("#yourJqueryDialogId").keydown(function(e) { if(e.which == 13) {
    $('#yourJqueryButtonId').click();
           return false;
      } });
```

Comment: This doesn't work if you click on the dialog somewhere before pressing enter.

Answer (score 0):

Simply use [keyup](http://api.jquery.com/keyup/) :

```
$(document).keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) // close the dialog
});
```